# ZF2 - How to retrieve a controller instance in Module.php?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2, widget

I am implementing a login widget via a view helper. I need to pass the instance of my authentication controller when creating the instance of the widget:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'loginWidget' => function (???) {
                $authController = ???
                return new \Application\View\Helper\LoginWidget($authController);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

The authentication controller is declared in the `module.config.php`:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Main\Controller\Index' => 'Main\Controller\IndexController',
        'Main\Controller\Auth'    => 'Main\Controller\AuthController'
    ),
),
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view helper shouldn't have to depend on a controller instance. You might consider extracting the code into a service and using the same service into the view helper and the auth controller.

Just in case this is not possible, I found the ZF2 source code responsible for controller instantiation:
https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/DispatchListener.php

We learn that controllers are build via the `ControllerManager` service. So you should be able to do something like this.

```
'loginWidget' => function ($helperPluginManager) {
    $authController = $helperPluginManager
        ->getServiceLocator()
        ->get('ControllerManager')
        ->get('Main\Controller\Auth')
    ;
    return new \Application\View\Helper\LoginWidget($authController);
}
```

Comment: I've tested it, but I get: Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for ControllerManager. I am going to try to move the code into a service.

Comment: I've edited to reflect the fact that the service manager is not passed directly to this anonymous factory.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is finding this page via Google and really does need to acquire the controller instance in module, this code works for me:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) 
{   
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function($e) {
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
    });
}
```

The `$controller` variable now stores an instance of the controller.